# Is there an infinite sequence AB, BC, CD, DX, ..., YZ

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, infinity

Is it possible to construct an infinite set of ordered pairs of form S = {(A, B), (B, C), (C, D), (D, x), ..., (y, Z)}?

Every element (B, C...) must appear only once as the first object in one of the pairs (except Z, never), and only once as the second object in one of the pairs (except A, never), and S is infinite.

I saw someone named sets similiar to the S above "R-paths" (the difference being that they were using only finite sets); basically if S (the set above) was a relation on some set A ($S \subseteq A^2$) then S would be an infinite R-path (an example of finite R-path would be {(A, B), (B, C), (C, D)}). My question can be then reformulated: *can we construct an infinite R-path (on any set)?*

My intuition is no, because at the path-point we got to after n steps, let's call it (N, M), the next path-point is either (M, not-the-end-point) or (M, end-point). The second option can't be right because we only traversed n path-points (and the path is infinite); but if first option is always right (that is, if the next step doesn't get us to the end), then there is no next-to-the-last path-point. This is probably useless since it only shows it is impossible to traverse (going one-by-one) such path (which was obvious from beginning), not that such path is impossible, but it might have to do with the actual annswer...

Thanks!

Comment: When you say each element $B, C, \ldots$ must appear only once as a first element, and only once as a second element, do you mean at most once each, or do you mean if it shows up once as one, it must also show up once as the other?

Comment: @ferson2020 The second one, basically if U is the set containing all elements that appear in the pairs of S, than for every element x of U, except for A and Z, there must be exactly one pair (x, _) and exactly one pair (_, x) in S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible, assuming that you have infinitely many objects available, but there will be an odd kind of gap in the middle. Suppose that I take $\Bbb N=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ as my set of objects to chain. Let $A=\{\langle n,n+2\rangle:n\text{ is even}\}$ and $B=\{\langle n+2,n\rangle:n\text{ is odd}\}$. Then I have the chain

$$\langle 0,2\rangle,\langle 2,4\rangle,\langle 4,6\rangle,\dots~\dots,\langle 7,5\rangle,\langle 5,3\rangle,\langle 3,1\rangle\;.$$

Technically it meets your requirements, but it probably isn’t what you really have in mind, since there’s no finite path from the even side to the odd side.

Comment: Thanks! And is it possible to do this without "gaps"? Not sure how would I formalize that requirement...

Comment: @Luka: You’re welcome! If there are no gaps of this kind, the chain must be finite: about the only way to formalize the absence of this kind of gap is to require that there be a finite chain between any two points.

Comment: Great, thanks again :)

Comment: @Luka: My pleasure.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. Let us define an order relation $\prec$ on $\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ by:

$$x \prec y  \iff -\frac{1}{x} < -\frac{1}{y}$$

We then have:
$$(1,2) \prec (2,3) \prec (3,4) \prec \cdots \prec (-4,-3) \prec (-3, -2) \prec (-2,-1)$$

with $1$ and $-1$ serving the roles of $A$ and $Z$.

Comment: Thanks! (stackexchange only allows one accepted answer per question so I could only give vote-up to yours)

Comment: @LukaMikec no problem. In any event, I think Brian has beaten my answer for 10 seconds.